# js textarea / jwysiwyg replacement

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically created textarea and like to replace it with jwysiwyg.
I tried to add the function in PHP template

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg();}); </script>
```

and in js file

```
njuid= ""+ actual.id +"_field";
act.innerHTML = "<textarea name=\"textarea\" id=\""+ act.id +"_field\"       onblur=\"noLight    (this); return fieldBlur(this,'" + actual.id + "');\">" +     actual.innerHTML + "</textarea> 
<script>$(function(){$('#+njuid').wysiwyg();});</script>";
```

without success. How can I replace the textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using jQuery to help you with the DOM manipulation. I have been able to create jWysiwyg dynamically in my pages by using the following strategy:

**1)** Append the textarea to the DOM wherever you need to. Do not set the contents of the textarea yet!

```
$('#myobject').append('<textarea id="textarea_'+id+'"></textarea>');
```

**2)** Create your wysiwyg and add whatever text you want to load into it as follows:

```
$('#textarea_'+id).wysiwyg().wysiwyg("clear").wysiwyg("insertHtml", "<div>whatever html</div>");
```